# NodeJS MySQL connection failing

Tags: mysql, node.js

I just added a mysql connection, but the script keeps failing. The error is below, and relevant js is below that.

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'loadClass.bind(null, 'Types')')

  app/node_modules/mysql/index.js:92
  app/node_modules/mysql/index.js:138
Error: Cannot find module 'crypto'

  phantomjs://bootstrap.js:289
  phantomjs://bootstrap.js:254 in require
  app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:1
  app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:420
TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Connection({config: new ConnectionConfig(config)})')

  app/node_modules/mysql/index.js:12 in createConnection
```

app.js

```
var Q = require("q");
var page = require('webpage').create();
//var crypto = require('./node_modules/crypto/sha1.js');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'shaun',
  password : 'somepassword',
  database : 'db'
});

connection.connect();
```

Comment: Does NodeJS default to SSL?

Comment: I would also look at these:
app/node_modules/mysql/index.js:12
app/node_modules/mysql/index.js:92
app/node_modules/mysql/index.js:138
app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:1
app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:420

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll have to open an issue on the SQL module. https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

Answer (score 0):

`Error: Cannot find module 'crypto'`

Have you tried `npm install crypto`? Does your app have a package.json? If so have you done `npm install`?

Comment: Yeah, I've installed crypto. This error is coming from a node module (from npm), https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql